# Masking input for ConvLSTM1D

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am doing a binary regression problem using keras.
The input shape is: `(None, 2, 94, 3)` (channels is the last dimension)

I have the following architecture:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(time, n_rows, n_channels))
masking = Masking(mask_value=-999)(input1)
convlstm = ConvLSTM1D(filters=16, kernel_size=15,
                      data_format='channels_last',
                      activation="tanh")(masking)
dropout = Dropout(0.2)(convlstm)
flatten1 = Flatten()(dropout)
outputs = Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid')(flatten1)
model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01))
```

However when training I get this error: `Dimensions must be equal, but are 94 and 80 for '{{node conv_lstm1d/while/SelectV2}} = SelectV2[T=DT_FLOAT](conv_lstm1d/while/Tile, conv_lstm1d/while/mul_5, conv_lstm1d/while/Placeholder_2)' with input shapes: [?,94,16], [?,80,16], [?,80,16].`

If I remove the masking layer this error disappears, what is the masking doing that triggers this error? Also the only way I was able to run the above architecture was with a `kernel_size` of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `ConvLSTM1D` layer needs a mask with the shape `(samples, timesteps)` according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM1D). The mask you are calculating has the shape `(samples, time, rows)`. Here is one solution to fix your problem but I am not sure if it is the 'correct' way to go:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2, 94, 3))
masking = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-999)(input1)
convlstm = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=16, kernel_size=15,
                      data_format='channels_last',
                      activation="tanh")(inputs = masking, mask = tf.reduce_all(masking._keras_mask, axis=-1))

dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(convlstm)
flatten1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(dropout)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(flatten1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01))
```

This line `mask = tf.reduce_all(masking._keras_mask, axis=-1)` essentially reduces your mask to `(samples, timesteps)` by applying an `AND` operation to the last dimension of the mask. Alternatively, you could just create your own custom mask layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Reduce(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self):
      super(Reduce, self).__init__()

  def call(self, inputs):
      return tf.reduce_all(tf.reduce_any(tf.not_equal(inputs, -999), axis=-1, keepdims=False), axis=1)

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2, 94, 3))
reduce_layer = Reduce()
boolean_mask = reduce_layer(input1)
convlstm = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=16, kernel_size=15,
                      data_format='channels_last',
                      activation="tanh")(inputs = input1, mask = boolean_mask)

dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(convlstm)
flatten1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(dropout)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(flatten1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01))
print(model.summary(expand_nested=True))
x = tf.random.normal((50, 2, 94, 3))
y = tf.random.uniform((50, ), maxval=3, dtype=tf.int32)
model.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. However how come training does not fail with a kernel_size of 1?

Comment: Also would timesteps be equal to rows*time?

Comment: As I said I am not sure if it is the correct way to go.. I was just following the docs ..

Comment: Also would timesteps be equal to rows*time? —> you can definitely try that

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct because I also have another model which takes an input shape of (None, 188, 3) and has a masking layer right after, after the masking comes the LSTM, which according to the docs needs a mask of shape (batch, timesetps). However the shape of the output of the Masking is the same as the input and I get no errors during training

Comment: So what I mean to say is the LSTM part of the ConvLSTM layer should know what to do when receiving the output of the Masking layer. But I'm not sure

Comment: I know what you mean but note that the LSTM layer and ConvLSTM layer behave differently

Comment: Agree, but the solution you provided transforms the mask to a shape of (None, 2) which is not what I would like. 2 is the number of subsequences of a given window of time. 94 is the number of timesteps in that subsequence and 3 is the number of features/channels